# What are the steps within `make_pipeline()`?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

What are the steps within `sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline()`?

The documentation doesn't explicitly state what are the steps that we "save" when using `make_pipeline()` instead of doing it the normal way. Was wondering what those steps are just for my understanding?
I can guess that one of the steps is applying a scaling to all columns in the dataset, like `StandardScaler()`.